Boruta: Why is the distribution of hits assumed to be Binomial(n, 0.5)?
I'm reading the original Boruta paper:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220443685_Boruta_-_A_System_for_Feature_Selection
When they describe the algorithm, they say that the number of "hits" in $n$ trials is distributed as Binomial($n$, 0.5). This is predicated on the assumption that, in a single trial, the probability that the importance value of a given feature exceeds the maximum importance value of the shadow features is 0.5.
I can't really see a good mathematical/probabilistic reason why things would necessarily be so simple.
Any clarifications would be gratefully received!
